# Running multiple applications with same profile on a single device (iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question, How can I run my multiple applications with the same profile (provisioning profile) on a single device? I have tried it but the previous application is getting overwritten by the new one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DipDhingani Sorry, that just not correct at all. You can run multiple applications on single device with same provisional profile provided it's a wildcard provisioning profile and they have different bundle ids

Comment: I am using a fully qualified provisioning profile and not wild card.

Comment: The comment I'd replied too has been deleted, but I can't delete mine now. However I don't think your problem can be solved without using a wildcard unless you use a separate provisioning profile for each

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided your provisioning profile is **wildcard**, (looks something like: com.company.*), if your applications have different bundle ids, they will create separate apps. This id seems to be what the iOS uses to distinguish different apps. If you aren't using a wild card, you would have to make a new provisioning profile for each version. =|

You can change this value in your plist.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need a wildcard app id and a provisioning profile for that app id. And the apps have to have different ids.

Answer (score -2):

Having separate Bundle identifier for each build will solve your problem.